# 7zip separate directories from a list of network paths

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, 7-zip

I have a .txt file containing 2400 separate network paths to directories that i need to 7zip into separate encrypted .7z files.

I believe i can do something like this in power shell however haven't gotten it to work so far

```
dir | ForEach-Object { & "7za.exe" a $_.BaseName $_.Name }
```

I've tried the following in a batch file, moving the batch file into the directory when the folders are i want to compress and it works, but i need it to read the directory paths from a txt file containing a list

Any suggestions?

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.7z" "%%X\"
```

Comment: In Powershell, you can pipe the file contents like: `gc paths.txt | % { }`.

Comment: Sometimes the dumb solution is the best: Copy the `.txt` file to a `.bat` file, record a macro in Notepad++ that massages the line and skips to the next, and run it 2400 times.

Answer (score 0):

So maybe something like this, for a simple pass at this. There are of course other ways of doing this.

```
# Read the file to parse
$NetworkPaths = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\NetworkPaths.txt'

# Loop through the list and split off path info to name and zip the files in the path provided
ForEach($NetworkPath in $NetworkPaths)
{ Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -ArgumentList "a -tzip D:\Temp\$(($NetworkPath.Split('\'))[-1]).zip $NetworkPath\*.* -r -pSECRET" -Wait}
```